# Reports/research about legalese texts

Tags: user-research, onboarding, reports, legal

I'm looking for any reports or user researches done related to legalese text in software. Apart from curiosity I'm mostly trying to find efficient methods for showing EULA (minimizing confusion for the user) and understand how users react to different approaches. Generally no one reads the EULA and my goal is not to enforce a new behavior, but I've seen different solutions that I react differently upon so I thought maybe someone more ambitious had already investigated in this.

Appreciate any help, thank you advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few resources related to this, as the EULA and other forms of contracts that are presented to users online are being scrutinised for their accessibility and user-friendliness.

There is a good article that gives you some of the general points to consider regarding the [UX of contracts](https://uxdesign.cc/the-ux-of-contract-27b4c5268fc8) as a starting point. It has some references to various analyses and references about the current state and why the user experience should be improved.

Finally, there is another article that provides some [heuristics for EULA](https://reullab.gatech.edu/eula-heuristics/) and will help with improving the design of EULA text that you might be able to find some good pointers.